# Update content in WebView on loading start in runtime

Tags: android, android-webview, android-webview-javascript

I need add same content on webview after loading start. For example, if I have web page:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

I need get

```
<same content/>
<head>
<head>
<body>
</body>
```

but `<same content/>` must be loaded before `<head>`
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by overwrite methods `loadData` and `loadDataWithBaseURL`